# How do I add a progress bar to a slideshow in Keynote?

Tags: macos, mac, iwork-keynote

I'm using Keynote (on OSX) and I want to show how far the presentation has progressed graphically.
Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the best way is to create a bar from left to right (think line) and copy paste it in the same position in all the slides.  Assuming you have 20 slides, you can reduce the length of the bar to indicate the progression in every slide.  As the presentation moves on to the next slide, the new length will show, progressing till the very end in the last slide.  May be simple, but effective.